# customise template to only show custom post type entries

Tags: custom-post-types, sidebar

How do I customize a template for a custom post type to only show the categories and recent entries for that post type?

I'm assuming that if my cpt is "newsletter", then I start with a single-newsletter.php file in my child theme.

Comment: look here : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/. the template to customise is `achives-newsletter.php`.

Comment: Thanks. I realize that what I want is to customize the sidebar on the single post type page, but I didn't write that clearly. Optimally, I'd like to add a filter to the query underneath get_sidebar(). Less optimally, filter the results.

Comment: if you want something special in the sidebar, you can create a new widget : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget

Comment: Register a new sidebar in `functions.php`, then edit `single-newsletter.php` to have it grab the new sidebar instead of the generic posts sidebar. Finally, you may need to create a widget or find a plugin that allows you to specify which taxonomies and CPT entries to display, then add that widget into the new sidebar in wp-admin.